# When is it better to use a Best-First-Search algorithm over a A* algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, a-star, breadth-first-search

So i'm a student and this is one of the possible questions for a exam, and i'm slightly confused because i thought A* was always a better choice.

thank you for the help.

Comment: Seems like a trick qeustion, as A* *is* Best First Search applied to a graph with an overall distance measure...

Answer (score 0):

A* is Best-first search basically. If you want variants and benchmarks, you can find more informations in this paper: http://www.cs.unh.edu/~ruml/papers/beam-socs10.pdf